# Display Facebook fql.query results with javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-fql

I am learning javascript and the Facebook API right now and I am trying to display the users newsfeed. I know the query I need to use but I don't know how to display the results using javascript. Here is my query

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0
```

I am pretty sure a forEach loop to display each result is what I need to do but how would I go about populating each result with the newsfeed post information?

#### EDIT

Ok here is my new code that does correctly receive the results of the query. Unfortunately, the results just aren't being shown.

```
<script>
               
function showPosts() {
    FB.api("/fql?q="+encodeURIComponent("SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0"), function(response, post_id, actor_id, message) {
    
    console.log(response);
  
    var posts = response.data
    var postId = post_id.data;
    var message = message.data;
  
    for (var i=0; i < posts.length && i < 25; i++) {
      var post = posts[i];
      
     markup += '<div>' + post.postId + post.message + '<div/>';
  }
  
    document.getElementById('newsfeedposts').innerHTML = markup;
  
});
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the query via FB.api, and handle the data you’ll be getting back in the callback function.

```
FB.api("/fql?q="+encodeURIComponent("SELECT ..."), function(response) {
  console.log(response);
})
```

Execute that in Firefox, look into the Firebug console, and you should get an understanding of how the response is constructed.

Comment: I am working in phonegap and when I view the app in a desktop browser, I can't login to Facebook. My login button won't work. Because of this, I can't use the api to call the users newsfeed so I am not getting any valuable info from the console.

Comment: Well, then use the Graph API Explorer and view the query results there, that also tells you what data format to expect -> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20post_id%2C%20actor_id%2C%20target_id%2C%20message%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20filter_key%20in%20(SELECT%20filter_key%20FROM%20stream_filter%20WHERE%20uid%3Dme()%20AND%20type%3D'newsfeed')%20AND%20is_hidden%20%3D%200

Comment: The Graph API Explorer helped a lot, thanks. I updated the op with the new script I am using. Do you know why the info won't display?

Comment: There is no variable/object called post_id available in the line of code where you try to do "var postId = post_id.data;" – so that’s a JavaScript error right there, which will terminate your script. Seriously, you should get/set up a development environment where you can have an error console if you want to script in JS with obviously rather little knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.api(

     'fql',


     {'q' : "SELECT url, like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://stackoverflow.com/';"},


     function (response){
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
     }

);
```